# How can I override standard error codes from `javax.validation` package?

Tags: java, validation, bean-validation

For example, for `@NotBlank` annotation I retrieve `NotBlank.className.fieldName` message code, but I need override this code with `"className.fieldName.canNotBeBlank"`:

```
@Entity
public class Customer {
..... minimized .....
    @NotNull
    @NotBlank(message = "customer.name.canNotBeBlanc")
    @Size.List({
       @Size(min = 2, message = "customer.name.minimalLengthIs2"),
       @Size(max = 50, message = "customer.name.maxlLengthIs50")
    })
    private String name;
..... minimized .....
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Petter and sorry for my English.

Comment: Check out this, maybe it can help while you are w8ing for answer http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkahi.html

Comment: Why? Why can't you organize your error message files according to the specification?

Comment: I wish to know which of validation rules isn't accepted and I wish to display specified error message for end user.

Comment: At this moment I see only one way - write my own validator which extends Validator interface. But for easy support I try to find another way, with out writing validator classes for each entity.

Comment: I am confused, what is your actual problem? The messages you are using are valid, however, if you want them to be used as keys to be looked up in a message bundle (ValidationMessages.properties) you will need to put them into curly braces as well, eg {customer.name.canNotBeBlanc}. For me it is really not clear what the question is.

Comment: Yes, I was trying do this `"{customer.name.canNotBeBlanc}"`, but the result is the same, I retrieve in my template: `NotBlank.customer.name` instead `customer.name.canNotBeBlanc`. May be I need put in my gradle script some dependency, for example `org.hibernate:hibernate-validation` or something else?